# Suddenly getting bsod memory management issue after Updating to windows 10

Tags: memory, bsod, windows-10

I recently upgraded to windows 10, most things seemd to work fine, aside from a few issues here and there which was easily resolved. Thou i had to reinstall the Nvivida Driver for the graphic card. (it was trying to run from the integrated motherbord graphic).

However i've suddenly been plagued with BSOD errors, both in page_....
and Memory management error, did a Windows memory diagonstics tool scan which showed hardware error, but gave no future explaination than that.

Is it possible that windows 10 is causeing the BSOD, were i just that unlucky and one of the RAm peices broke during the installation of windows 10 ?
Any suggestion/tips is appreciated.

Whocrashed now gives crashlog

```
crash dump file: C:\Minidump\073115-4656-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x14D220) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1A (0x41792, 0xFFFFF68000036000, 0x20000000, 0x0)
Error: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
file path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: This indicates that a severe memory management error occurred.
This might be a case of memory corruption. More often memory corruption happens because of software errors in buggy drivers, not because of faulty RAM modules. 
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.
```

Setting up a memtest86+ (thanks for the tip)

Also the info from Bluescreen view gives this info.

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 080215-7531-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 02.08.2015 13.37.26
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00041792
Parameter 2       : fffff6bf`fe555000
Parameter 3       : 00000000`20000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Minidump\080215-7531-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 263 550
Dump File Time    : 02.08.2015 13.38.13
==================================================
```

Adding a secound mini dump.

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 080115-6703-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 01.08.2015 22.15.10
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00041793
Parameter 2       : fffff680`001db080
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000011
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000010
Caused By Driver  : win32kfull.sys
Caused By Address : win32kfull.sys+d329f
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Minidump\080115-6703-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 265 086
Dump File Time    : 01.08.2015 22.15.57
==================================================
```

I must thank you all again for your assistance and time.

Will add the kernel dump, the next time it crashes (switched it from making a mini dump to a kernel dump).

Comment: You should run Memtest86+ which is bootable and scans your memory without windows being loaded. That way you can easily see if its the hardware or software that isn't working properly.

Comment: What are the BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: I'll get my memory stick later to set up memtest86+ And thank you for your time and assistance. I'll try to get the full minidump up, but the usual view system i used for windows 8.1 dosn't appear to read the minidump file correctly

Comment: 0x41792 = *A corrupted PTE has been detected. Parameter 2 contains the address of the PTE. Parameters 3/4 contain the low/high parts of the PTE.* I need the kernel dump (C:\Windows\Memory.dmp) to see more details.

Comment: Alright, i'll have it create a kernel dump for the next time it crashes (about once a day). Will Update the original question with the kernel dump information when i aquire it.

Comment: Strangely i havn't had another crash.. i suppose ill have to try and work the system to it'll use more ram.

Comment: Had similar situation and never solved it. Was badly related to graphic card drivers by what I found, too old

Answer (score 0):

I had the same BSOD and the http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm (booted in UEFI mode) revealed that the RAM is broken around gigabyte nr. 4.

After removing the first 8gb module, it detects no more problems.

I had been running Windows 8.1 and a memtest86 a month ago without any problems, so I hope its not Windows 10 that caused the RAM to break.